# Linq Extension Methods and Error Handling

Tags: c#, linq, error-handling, extension-methods

I have the following C# code...

```
    // We're essentially pivoting the data, using LINQ's GroupBy.
    var pivotedOperands = Operands.GroupBy(o => new { outputid = (Guid)o[DETAILS_OUTPUTID], unitid = o[DETAILS_UNITID] })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            PivotKey = g.Key,
            c1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[DETAILS_OV_SEQUENCEID] == 1).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[DETAILS_VALUE].ToString())),
            r1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[DETAILS_OV_SEQUENCEID] == 2).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[DETAILS_VALUE].ToString())),
            a1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[DETAILS_OV_SEQUENCEID] == 3).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[DETAILS_VALUE].ToString()))
        });
```

It takes the data in Operands (which is a List object) and uses the GroupBy() extension method to perform a pivot on the data.  Essentially c1, r1 and a1 are all values in different DataRow objects with sequence IDs of 1, 2 and 3 respectively.   (I can go into more detain on that if it becomes necessary, but I think it won't.)

So sometimes the value for c1 might be empty.  (It's not supposed to, but bugs have happened further upstream in the process from time to time.)  If c1 is not a numeric value, the double.Parse() call will raise an exception.  That's fine.  Here's my problem.  If the Operands object contains, for example, 9 rows that will be pivoted into 3 rows and one of those nine values is not numeric, is it possible to determine which DataRow object raised the exception?

example:
If Operands contains the following values for SequenceID and Value...

```
OutputID UnitID SequenceID Value
A        1      1          '0'
A        1      2          '0'
A        1      3          '0'
A        2      1          ''
A        2      2          '0'
A        2      3          '0'
B        1      1          '0'
B        1      2          '0'
B        1      3          '0'
```

...then we will get an "Input string was not in a correct format" exception when it tries to process the empty string through the double.Parse() method for the 4th row of my data set.  I want to raise a friendly exception to the users telling them which row is the problem; not just that there was a problem somewhere in this set of data.  Is it possible to identify exactly what caused the exception?

If you create a new C# console application in Visual studio and dump the following code into the Main method, you will be able to reproduce my problem.

```
        // Create a DataTable so that we can easily create new DataRows to add to our List.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        col.ColumnName = "OutputID";
        dt.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        col.ColumnName = "UnitID";
        dt.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        col.ColumnName = "SequenceID";
        dt.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        col.ColumnName = "Value";
        dt.Columns.Add(col);



        // Create the List and add our sample data
        List<DataRow> Operands = new List<DataRow>();

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 1;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 2;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 3;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "2";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 1;
        dr["Value"] = "";       // This should cause an error.
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "2";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 2;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "A";
        dr["UnitID"] = "2";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 3;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "B";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 1;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "B";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 2;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["OutputID"] = "B";
        dr["UnitID"] = "1";
        dr["SequenceID"] = 3;
        dr["Value"] = "0";
        Operands.Add(dr);

        // Now pivot the data
        try
        {
            var pivotedOperands = Operands.GroupBy(o => new { outputid = o[0], unitid = o[1] })
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    PivotKey = g.Key,
                    c1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[2] == 1).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[3].ToString())),
                    r1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[2] == 2).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[3].ToString())),
                    a1 = g.Where(x => (int)x[2] == 3).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[3].ToString()))
                });

            foreach (var o in pivotedOperands)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("c1 = {0}; r1 = {1}; a1 = {2}", o.c1, o.r1, o.a1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head using select with an index and also using TryParse to get around the exception. if tryparse false then record index. Or if tryparse false default to zero (0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you want the information surfaced, you can either change the type of your results to account for the possibility of failure, or you can capture contextual information about the exception and throw a new exception with more information in it.

In either case, don't be afraid to use helper methods. For example, suppose you got rid of the repetitive code in your selector by creating a method like this:

```
string GetSumOrErrorMessage(int idToMatch, IEnumerable<DataRow> dataRow)
{
    try
    {
        var sum = dataRow.Where(x => (int)x[2] == idToMatch).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[3].ToString()));
        return sum.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Error happened here"; // or something more specific
    }
}
```

Now you can change your query like this:

```
    var pivotedOperands = Operands.GroupBy(o => new { outputid = o[0], unitid = o[1] })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            PivotKey = g.Key,
            c1 = GetSumOrErrorMessage(1, g),
            r1 = GetSumOrErrorMessage(2, g),
            a1 = GetSumOrErrorMessage(3, g)
        });
```

And your output turns into:

> ```
> c1 = 0; r1 = 0; a1 = 0
> c1 = Error happened here; r1 = 0; a1 = 0
> c1 = 0; r1 = 0; a1 = 0
> ```

If you like this pattern, rather than just returning a `string` you may want to look into specialized Monadic types that can help with this. For example, you could create a class that has a generic value when an action is successful, or an error message when it's not. You can create a variety of extension methods and helpers to make this easier to deal with, similar to how [my CallMeMaybe library](https://github.com/j2jensen/callmemaybe) would allow you to attempt to parse a value, but just return an empty `Maybe<>` if parsing fails. (e.g. `Maybe.From(x[3].ToString()).ParseInt64().Select(i => i.ToString()).Else("Error happened here")`).

Alternatively, if you actually want to halt when you get bad input, but still want to know where the bad input was, you can catch and throw:

```
double GetSum(int idToMatch, IGrouping<object, DataRow> dataRows)
{
    try
    {
        return dataRows.Where(x => (int)x[2] == idToMatch).Sum(x => double.Parse(x[3].ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Failure when matching {idToMatch} with group {dataRows.Key}", e);
    }
}
```

...

```
    var pivotedOperands = Operands.GroupBy(o => new { outputid = o[0], unitid = o[1] })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            PivotKey = g.Key,
            c1 = GetSum(1, g),
            r1 = GetSum(2, g),
            a1 = GetSum(3, g)
        });
```

Output:

> ```
> c1 = 0; r1 = 0; a1 = 0
> Failure when matching 1 with group { outputid = A, unitid = 2 }
> ```

Comment: Beautiful.  It never occurred to me to do this.  And with the helper method I get enough control over execution to handle more unusual cases.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You try using `TryParse` to get around the exception. If TryParse is false then default to zero (`0`)

```
.Sum(x => { 
    double value = 0; 
    return double.TryParse(x[DETAILS_VALUE].ToString(), out value) ? value : 0; 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I went with StriplingWarrior's answer because it give me the flexibility to either use a default value if the parsing fails, or raise the exception and break execution.  (Which is exactly what I need.)

Comment: @DeadZone it's all good. That was the better choice if you wanted to actually catch the exception. glad to offer help.